# Attendance Management System

Tags: php, open-source, time-and-attendance

I am looking for an open source Attendence Management System, I'd like to be able to customise functions.

Please recommend some written in PHP.

I am running BPO with around 20 employees.

I want to track their daily check-in and check-out time.

Thanks
Bharanikumar

Comment: DO YOU REALLY HAVE TO YELL IT OUT?!

Comment: And what does an attendance management system do exactly? You best add some details.

Comment: If you want to add emphasis, **use bold.**

Comment: @Dave you mean like **ATTENDANCE MANAGEMENT SYSTEM**? ;)

Comment: @Gordon lol hopefully not... ow my eyes hurt...

Comment: @Dennis attenDANCE? like in SquareDance? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what an attendance management system would have to be able to do exactly, but take a look at the PHP section on [opensourcecms.com](http://www.opensourcecms.com/). They have a number of calendars, project management tools etc. to test drive, maybe one of them comes close to what you need - it's often just a matter of renaming labels or categories.

Comment: @Bharanikumar if u found this answer is helpful for u, u should provide the proper link where u find your solution as this link leads us to a listing...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried TimeTrex [Time and Attendance](http://www.timetrex.com)? Its open source and extremely configurable.

Answer (score 1):

[Attendance Management System](http://sourcecodemania.com/attendance-management-system/) is written in PHP and released as an open source project under GPL v3. This software is web based and easier to setup.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this freeware that I found for you.

[phpTime sheet](http://www.vclcomponents.com/PHP/Groupware_Tools/phpTime_Sheet-info.html)

I noticed that the files have extention php3 but don't worry they are normal php files. Enjoy!

> php Time sheet is an important and powerful program and helpful for / business persons and for individual users to handle their data, it might be personal or employee and also it is useful for web based accounting, managing holidays, project tracking and attendance of employees etc., MySQL database is used to store data.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a fairly specific request for a timesheet system. There's lots around, mostly web based. But I have to ask ....

Is this a question for this forum?

Answer (score 0):

With these requirements, this is easier solved with Excel/OpenOfficeCalc/GoogleSpreadsheets/etc

Comment: Not really, redundant data, and non updated data on employee computers if they have their own would be a problem.

Comment: no ..actually, i like to mantain all these records in the database..

Comment: Ya and you would probably want some kind of automation here and there.

Comment: @Jonathan how likely is it to have 20 employees but no central file server? Redundant data is barely an issue here, all he wants to record is employee name (could be the filename), date, time in, time out. And them not updating can happen with a database or webapp too.

Comment: hi looking some open source..i dont like to take much more time to build appli..if open source there, then i will customise

Comment: @Bharanikumar if a (specific) database or license is a requirement, you should add that to your question, along with any other special functions you need. Right now, what you are asking for can be written in PHP in a matter of one hour.